# Date not appearing JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

The date is not appearing on the webpage. Need help in identifying the problem please.

> HTML

```
 <p class = 'copyright-year'></p>
```

> JavaScript

```
const yearEl = document.querySelector('.copyright-year');
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear();
yearEl.innerText = year;
```

Comment: it is working fine. Seems you are adding js in head section so it is not able to find the dom. Add it using `window.onload`

Comment: I have an external js file for this. Does'nt external js work for this?

Comment: If you are adding external js file in head then remove from there and add it near closong body tag like this `<body>..rest of code <script src='Your js scrip'>t</script></body>`

Comment: It worked, may I know what window.onload does? I am just a beginner so I don't know much :(

Comment: Perhaps you can create a codepen.io for us.

Comment: @Redd: please read the docs. [JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/js) are really helpful.

Comment: You can't eat an apple before you bought it. `window.onload` waits for the DOM to be rendered, or for the apple to be bought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and Your code is already Correct; maybe you writed **Javascript** codes in other file and don't pass path to html;

Answer (score 1):

It's working well normally but I tried to reproduce your issue like this.
In this case, It will throw this issue. **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null"**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const yearEl = document.querySelector('.copyright-year');
            const date = new Date();
            const year = date.getFullYear();
            yearEl.innerText = year;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class = 'copyright-year'></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

So for resolving this issue, there are two options.
Firstly, please use that script tag before body tag closed or you need to run that script after dom content is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // your current script codecode...
});
```

Wish it might help you a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly, my guess is you have placed the js link at the top of your html file. You must keep it just above the  tag and you are good to go.